# VBA Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range for similar sheets to convert to text files

Tags: excel, vba

I have used this macro several times, but not getting runtime error 9, subscript out of range today? The format of the sheet appears to be the same. Any suggestions on how to correct?

```
Sub SaveRowsAsTXT()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim rowRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

filePath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Working\SomeName\"

For Each cell In Range("B1", Range("B10").End(xlUp))
    Set rowRange = Range(cell.Address, Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight))

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking

    r = 1
    Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        For c = 2 To 16
            wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
        Next c
        fileName = filePath & wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value

        wsTemp.Move
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)

        wbNew.SaveAs fileName & ".txt", xlTextWindows 'save as .txt
        wbNew.Close
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        r = r + 1
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few reasons that you could get this error. It could be that the sheet you are referring to does not exist. Also it could be that your application is losing focus when trying to reference something inside of it. To help pin point the problem, try setting a break point when running the code to see which line exactly is failing